# Cognitive Services makeRequest always returns undefined

Tags: node.js, return, azure-cognitive-services

I am using Microsoft Cognitive Services api for nodejs (joshbalfour/node-cognitive-services). I have followed the code as per the documentation example. However I have found that the response is always 'undefined'.

```
    face.listPersonGroups({
      parameters
    })
    .then((response) => {
        console.log('Got response:', response); //always undefined?
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error('Encountered error making request:', err);
    });
```

This is calling face.js from the repo, makeRequest is actually making the request.

```
  return verifyParameters(operation, parameters)
        .then(makeRequest({
            operation,
            parameters,
            API_KEY
        }));
```

If i log the output to console in api.js then I can see the actual response from the cognitive services API (200 OK).

```
    const makeRequest = ({operation, parameters, body, API_KEY}) => {
    let headers = {
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': API_KEY
    };
    let path = operation.uriTemplate;
    operation.parameters.forEach((param) => {
        if (parameters[param.name] && param.type == 1){
            path = path.split(`{${param.name}}`).join(parameters[param.name]);
            parameters[param.name] = undefined;
        }
    });

    let uri = `${operation.scheme}://${operation.host}/${path}`;
    const options = {
        uri,
        method: operation.method,
        headers,
        qs: parameters,
        json: true,
        body
    };
//if you output the response from 'rp' here we get the actual result (200 OK)

    return rp(options);
```

So the actual call to the API is working fine but returning the value is not. If anyone is able to explain why the response in my controller is always 'undefined' that would be very helpful.

Comment: I think there's a bug in the api code. `.then(makeRequest({operation, parameters, API_KEY}));` should be `.then(return makeRequest({operation,parameters,API_KEY}));`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Maria Ines Parnisari you pointed me in the right direction and Ive resolved it. It looks like the issue is with the API. Ive fixed by adding a function to .then as simply returning makeRequest gives an error.

```
        return verifyParameters(operation, parameters)
        .then(function () {
          return makeRequest({
            operation,
            parameters,
            API_KEY
        })});
```